# How should I organise an object to to keep everything as decoupled as possible?

Tags: javascript

I am finally asking this question as I have never actually found an answer. If I have a javascript object with a structure such as this:

```
var someObj = {

    "categoryA" : {
        "func1" : function(){},
        "func2" : function(){},
    },

    "categoryB" : {
        "func3" : function(){},
        "func4" : function(){},
    }

}
```

`func4` wants to call `func2`. Do I have any way of calling it without saying `someObj.func2()`? It seems to me this is ugly since it is ensuring the application cannot be easily renamed and appears to be more tightly coupling the internal functions. Or is this just how it is typically organised and it is not seen as a problem?

Comment: you didn't got an answer because the only valid answer is that you have very high expectations with your js object.

Comment: Removed JSON from your title because it really has nothing to do with JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always refractor your object declaration into something that looks like this :

```
var someObj = (function() {

    function func1(){}
    function func2() {}
    function func3() {}

    function func4() {
        func2();
    }

    var self = {
        "categoryA" : {
            "func1" : func1,
            "func2" : func2,
        },

        "categoryB" : {
            "func3" : func3,
            "func4" : func4,
        }
    };

    return self;
}());
```

It's commonly called the "Module Pattern".

Comment: Hi. Whenever I have seen the module pattern it has just been in small examples and as such I have (probably incorrectly) assumed it is not how a larger scale application would be organised.

A further question then: If I organised it like you have said above, and then wanted to dynamically load in "categoryC" and add this into my obj, how will that work? If I want the functions of categoryC to use those of the other categories, I think I'm back to using someObj.func2()?

Comment: @TedTedTed It always depends on what your project needs. From my experience it's really useful to use them in large scale project, because when you divide your code in small module, each of these module have their own internal state that nothing else can touch. The variable and function that are declared inside the module are "private" (as long as you don't return them).

Comment: @TedTedTed I'm not too sure about what you mean by "dynamically load" other category, but as long as your `categoryC` is declared inside your "module" it will have access to the other member and you will be able to call the function directly.

Comment: Ok ace. I think I'll try refactoring an app I'm working on at the moment following this format and see how I get on. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

It's not really possible for the following reason. Imagine something like this:

```
var obj1 = {}, obj2 = {};

var categoryA = {
    "func1" : function(){},
    "func2" : function(){},
};

var categoryB = {
    "func3" : function(){},
    "func4" : function(){},
};

obj1.categoryA = categoryA;
obj1.categoryB = categoryB;

obj2.categoryA = categoryA;
obj2.categoryB = categoryB;
```

You can see that `obj2.categoryB.func4()` wouldn't know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use some "private" variable name for using inside your module ('me' in my example) and "export" it to another variable for outside use ('someObj').

```
var someObj = (function(){
  var me = {
    A:{
      fn1:function() {return 1}
    },
    B:{
      fn2:function() {return me.A.fn1()}
    }
  };
  return me;
})();

someObj.B.fn2()
```